# is It right to create a single instance in another cls + load method in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <anthercls.h>
+ (void)load
{
    [anothercls sharedInstance];
}
```

What puzzles me is when the class's load message is called, does another class is loaded in memory? How to ensure that another class was loaded before the class. because of `#import`?

I have searched for a while，but can't get a satisfying answer.

Comment: May be `initialize` will suit for your purpose better. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I saw some codes in our project like this.

Comment: I think it's not right. It will unnecessary increase app loading time + it's unknown in which order runtime will load classes and it's not 100% possibility that  `anothercls` already got loaded when yours class is loading. In most cases I think it does nothing.

Comment: Yes, it can`t ensure another class has loaded before using it in the load method. I agree with you.

Comment: @BingchenQin In general, you should avoid using `+load` or `+initialize` as much as possible and, if you do use them, don't do any "heavy lifting".

Comment: @BingchenQin There is a bunch of information here about the implementation details and why +load/+initialize are so problematic.  http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/06/iniailize-can-be-executed-multiple-times-load-not-so-much/

Answer (score 0):

You can't know the order in which `+load` is called, with exceptions: when`+load` is called on a class in your app there are classes that are guaranteed to have been already loaded:

- classes from frameworks you link to
- superclass of the class `+load` is currently executed

So if `anothercls` is a class from a framework you link to, it's safe to use it. [More about +load and +initialize here](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html)

Comment: Yes, but another class is a customized class, and don`t have any relation to the +load class. I saw this code in my company project, I think it has some potential error when running. just has #import between them

Comment: so it's safe to use framework classes. Your superclasses are also guaranteed to be fully loaded, so they are safe to use as well.  
So, the framework mention above just are dynamic frameworks?